# Как найти значение второй производной в точке?

Tags: c#, математика

есть метод
`double Function(double x) { return Math.Log10(x) + x - 2; }`
Для метода хорд (метод нахождения корня нелинейного уравнения) мне нужно найти неподвижный конец из заданного интервала [a,b]. Он ищется по формуле Function(a)*Functiond2(x)>0. Если это условие выполняется, то значит что a - неподвижный конец. Я не могу понять, как найти Functiond2(a)(Functiond2 - подразумевается как вторая производная) не вводя отдельно вручную формулу второй производной функции. Как мне это сделать численно? Я нашел вроде как найти значение первой производной, это по формуле (f(x + dx) - f(x))/dx, где dx=double.MinValue как я понял(или неправильно понял). Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если надо численно, то проще всего

```
f''(x) = (f(x+dx)-2*f(x)+f(x-dx))/(dx*dx)
```

Но численное дифференцирование — занятие не самое веселое и очень подверженное ошибкам (представления, округления и т.д., в отличие от численного интегрирования).

Так что выбор подходящего `dx` должен выполняться с осторожностью: слишком большое — получаем погрешность метода, слишком малое — погрешность округления...

Comment: как вывести данную формулу?

Comment: @Space Как разность первых производных справа и слева

Answer (score 0):

Производная по определению есть отношение приращения функции к приращению аргумента. То есть (y1-y0)/(x1-x0), получается если вы сделаете так на точке f0, то получите 1 производную точки f0. Для второй производной вам нужны точки f0 и f1, получаете производные в этих точках(f0' и f1') и далее вычисляете так же (f1'-f0')/(x1-x0).

Таким образом напишите функцию, где будет вычислять производная и передавайте ей 2 точки (x0 y0) и (x1 y1) а что это будут за точки - дело ваше хотите туда отправляйте исходную функцию, хотите первую производную, а хотите и вторую:)

```
f''(x) =( f'(x+dx) - f'(x) )/ dx
```

Comment: я не совсем понял как это реализовать на языке. f1 я так понял это Function(x), что тогда означает f0? Как мне вообще вычислять производную тогда?

Comment: @Андрей вам придется брать 2 точки для того, чтобы найти производную в одной точке. Даже если вы напишите x0 + dx, то вот эта сумма и есть новая точка. Поэтому чтобы найти производную в точке x0, вы должны отступить на чуть-чуть(чем меньше тем лучше, но это не значит что в вашем случае не хватит 0.001, не нужно писать 0.00000001). Вот когда вы отступили на 0.1 допустим у вас появляется x1 = x0+0.1, и вы смотрите а насколько сильно за такой маленький шажок изменился y, потом находите отношение.Если y изменился сильно, то и производная будет "большой" величины,а если точно так же,например, то 1

Comment: я понял. Беру x0=a, x1=a+0.0001. fd(a) = (f(x1) - f(x0))/(x1-x0). Но тогда fd(a) - будет значением перовой производной в точке a. Но как мне тогда найти значение второй производной в a? Передавать в качестве y0=fd(a), а в качестве y1=fd(a)+0.0001, а x0 и x1 оставить без изменений?

Comment: чтобы найти значение 2 производной в точке а, вам нужны значения 1 производной в точке a и в точке a+0.0001 и далее теперь для этих 2 точек проделать то же самое, с  теми же x0 и x1.
df(a+0.0001)-fd(a) / (x+0.0001 - x)